# Handle NULL values when reading through OracleDataReader?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, null, datareader

I'm working on my first ASP.Net application, and seem to be hitting a lot of hurdles (background primarily in WinForms with a recent MVC5 project under my belt).

I am successfully making my DB connection using `OracleCommand` and executing my query, but when I try reading through the rows I am getting a `Column contains NULL value` on the second row for `odr.GetDecimal(1)`. Anyone know how to handle null values when reading through an OracleDataReader?

Below is my code:

```
        List<YearsOfService> yearsOfService = new List<YearsOfService>();
        string SQL = "SELECT SCHOOL_YEAR as YEAR, " +
                            "TOTAL_SERVICE_CREDIT as ServiceCredited, " +
                            "RETIREMENT_SALARY as Salary, " +
                            "SOURCE_VALUE as CoveredEmployer " +
                     "FROM " + Schema + ".RANDOM_ORACLE_TABLE a " +
                     "WHERE MEMBER_ACCOUNT_ID = :memberAccountId";

        DbConnection dbc = new DbConnection();
        OracleCommand cmd = dbc.GetCommand(SQL);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("memberAccountId", memberAccountId));
        OracleDataReader odr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        int counter = 0;
        if (odr.HasRows)
        {
            while (odr.Read())
            {
                YearsOfService yos = new YearsOfService();
                yos.Year = odr.GetInt16(0);
                yos.ServiceCredited = odr.GetDecimal(1); // Error on Second Pass

                yos.Salary = odr.GetDecimal(2);

                yos.CoveredEmployer = odr.GetString(3);

                yearsOfService.Add(yos);
                counter++;
            }
        }

        return yearsOfService;
    }
```

I had thought a simple check for NULL and if so replace with 0 (since expecting a `Decimal` value) would work with the following, but no luck. Same error: `yos.ServiceCredited = Convert.IsDBNull(odr.GetDecimal(1)) ? 0 : odr.GetDecimal(1);`.

Full error is:

**An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll but was not handled in user code**

**Additional information: Column contains NULL data**

I have confirmed that my 2 rows being returned are in the following format:

```
Year|CreditedService|Salary  |CoveredEmployer
2013|0.70128        |34949.66|ER
2014|NULL           | 2213.99|NULL
```

Anyone have advice on how best to proceed? How should I handle receiving the NULL value when reading through my OracleDataReader?

Comment: just curious on this particular line `yos.ServiceCredited = odr.GetDecimal(1);` how come you are not referencing the field by name and the checking it value prior to just assigning the value..?
`Look up Null Coalesce`

Comment: I haven't used OracleDataReader, but I'd guess you need to check if `odr.GetValue(1)` is NULL instead of `odr.GetDecimal(1)`.

Comment: check for odr.GetValue(0) != DBNull.Value

Comment: Another option would be to coalesce the value in the SQL.

Comment: @DJKRAZE, not sure I follow what you mean. Will look up Coalesce though. @juharr: I tried that, but then I get an error either way as `yos.ServiceCredited` is expecting a  `Decimal` value, not just `object` from `GetValue()`. @Syed: Tried that one, no luck, same error.

Comment: oh, actually I used that with SqlDataReader worked fine so I thought it may work with OracleDataReader too :P

Comment: btw you should dispose your connection and cmd...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
yos.ServiceCredited = odr.IsDBNull(1) ? 0 : odr.GetDecimal(1);
```

`OracleDataReader` provides a `IsDBNull()` method.

And the docs on [`GetDecimal()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.getdecimal(v=vs.110).aspx) ask us to do this

> Call IsDBNull to check for null values before calling this method.

Comment: Thanks Abhi, this did the trick! I had tried using the `IsDBNull()` method earlier, but I was implementing it incorrectly. Previously I think I tried something like `yos.ServiceCredited = Convert.IsDBNull(odr.GetDecimal(1))`. This is my first time using `OracleDataReader` and I'm inexperienced with how it does the "column" references using the different `Get()`'s. Thanks for your help!

Comment: thanks for this.  Anyone else think it's absolute madness that a Client has to make a pre-check call like this to find out if the value is Null before you read it?  Why doesn't `GetDecimal()` (etc) just return a Null value like every other DB driver?  Seems crazy

Comment: @Black I guess that's what we get for using Oracle?

Comment: @Black Because a Decimal value cannot be null. If the method were able to return null as you describe, you would have to always check the result wasn't null anyway in order to assign it to a Decimal.

Comment: @AndyHames They should use `default` like anyone sane.