# How to convert a value if it's null

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion, dbnull

I am using C#

```
Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["Termination_Date"])
```

rdr is defined as

```
OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

The Termination_Date field in the table maybe null. How do I check if it's null and set a date like 01/01/0001

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @epascarello C#

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handle NULL values when reading through OracleDataReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024722/handle-null-values-when-reading-through-oracledatareader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to access the column by name, you can compare against [`DBNull.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull.value?view=net-6.0) with something like a ternary statement to pick between `DateTime.MinValue` (1/1/0001) and the result of converting the non-null value.

```cs
OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

DateTime terminationDate = rdr["Termination_Date"] == DBNull.Value
    ? DateTime.MinValue
    : Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["Termination_Date"]);
```

You can do this more concisely with [`OracleDataReader.IsDBNull()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.isdbnull?view=netframework-4.8) and [`OracleDataReader.GetDateTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.getdatetime?view=netframework-4.8) if you know the column index (assume that our desired value is the first column in the result).

```cs
OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

DateTime terminationDate = rdr.IsDBNull(0)
    ? DateTime.MinValue
    : rdr.GetDateTime(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DateTime result = DateTime.MinValue;
int index = rdr.GetOrdinal("Termination_Date");
if(!rdr.IsDbNull(index))
   result = rdr.GetDateTime(index);
```

Reference:  [OracleDataReader.GetDateTime(Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracledatareader.getdatetime?view=netframework-4.8)

An explanation: with `DataReader` classes, database nulls come across as the value `DBNull.Value`. You need to check for that value (there are various methods) before attempting to convert to the desired data type.

`DateTime.MinValue` is equivalent to 1/1/0001.

If you'd like to segue into using nullable variables rather than a "special value" to symbolize "no value", you could try this extention method (done from memory):

```
public static class Extensions {

    public static T? GetNullableValue<T>(
       this System.Data.Common.DbDataReader reader, 
       string columnName) where T : struct {
   
         var ordIndex = reader.GetOrdinal(columnName);
         if(reader.IsDbNull(ordIndex))
             return null;
         else
             return (T?) reader.GetValue(ordIndex)
     }
}
```